# Relationship between the equation $e_1 +e_2 + e_3 = 17$ et the expansion

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> Find the number of solution of $e_1 +e_2 + e_3 = 17$, where $e_1$,
>   $e_2$ and $e_3$ are nonnegative integers with $2 \leq e_1 \leq 5$, $3
>  \leq e_2 \leq 6$ and $4 \leq e_1 \leq 7$.
>
> **Solution :**
>
> The number of solutions with the indicated constraints is the
>   coefficient of $x^{17}$ in the expansion of $$(x^2 + x^3 + x^4 +
>  x^5)(x^3 + x^4 + x^5 + x^6)(x^4 + x^5 + x^6 + x^7)$$
>   The coefficient is 3.

I don't understand why there is an equivalence between the question and expansion. I already know that $x^{17} = x^{e_1} x^{e_2} x^{e_3}$. I have some intuition, but I don't understand fully. Will someone be able to explain this relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were to completely expand the brackets then the coefficient of $x^9$ would be $1$. You can see this by multiplying the leftmost variable in each bracket. What this means is that with the given constraints for $e_1, e_2, e_3$ there's only one way for the numbers to add up to $9$, which is by taking the smallest value for each $e$.

Now what about the coefficient of $x^{10}$. That would be $3$ which you can see by selecting the smallest power from two of the brackets and from the third bracket you choose the second smallest power, multiply the 3 chosen variable(each from a different bracket) and you should get $x^{10}$. There's three ways to do this, so when you completely expand the brackets you would get $x^9 + x^{10} + x^{10} + x^{10} + x^{11} +...$
Essentially, what you're doing is finding solutions to the equation $e_1+e_2+e_3=10$

So the coefficient for $x^{17}$ can be interpreted as how many ways you can select three variable each from a different bracket, such that when you multiply them the solution is $x^{17}$. Can you see how this relates to the equation $e_1+e_2+e_3=17$

Answer (score 2):

Multiplying is choosing one element from the first factor, one from the second and one from the third. And doing this for every different combination.

When a choice yields a product equal to $x^{17}$ then it comes from an admissible combination that verifies your conditions $e_1+e_2+e_3=17$. Every such combination produced exactly one $x^{17}$. The constant factor of $x^{17}$ in the development is therefore the number of such admissible choices.